# Automatically hint/complete Google Chrome site search shortcut in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, search, address-bar

Does anyone know a way for site shortcuts to be shown as hints or autocompleted with some keyboard shortcuts?

For example, I set this up in Chrome settings:

- Name: `Super User`
- Shortcut: `@su`
- Search: `https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%s`

I would like to be able to press `@s` in address bar then and either select the defined `@su` by pressing <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> in listing below or pressing some key to scroll through all possible search combinations, just like you'd do with <kbd>Tab</kbd> in some CLI shells. Or, another example, list defined `@test` after you type `@t`.

I couldn't find anything similar. Any sort of solution is welcome.

Comment: I oon't know if I understand you corretly, buy presssing Tab after typing `@su` should allow you to then type your search query for Superuser.

Comment: You misunderstood. The question specifically mentions entering `@s` and automatically getting defined `@su` in a way or another, e.g. from the dropdown that appears. Or typing `@t` to then automatically get `@test`, for instance. Pressing Space after typing `@su` also works for what you're writing BTW.

Comment: Sent a feature request since it's impossible I'm pretty sure https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1477380